# Ruby: How to delete files and folders under C:\Users\ for specified Username

Tags: ruby, directory, fileutils

Basically I want to create a program that can delete 3 directories and a file in preparation for a software's "Rebuild" that needs to be done every so often for troubleshooting purposes.

The problem is, it needs to be used on multiple computers with different users and originally I just had a batch program that I would have to edit the corresponding username into. I'm trying to automate this.

How can I make it so that what's entered for Username gets put in the `FileUtils.rm_rf path?` I tried doing `${Username}` `#{Username}` and `@{Username}`, none of them seemed to work?

Also how can I make it so if the specific file isn't found it will return a custom message instead of a ruby error?

Thanks in advance! and sorry for my noobness, this is my first post and I am VERY new to ruby (I even googled how to use 'goto' in ruby!)

```
require 'fileutils'
puts "Please enter in your username:"
Username = gets.chomp
def question?
    puts "Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/N)"
    case gets.strip
    when 'Y', 'y', 'yes' 'Yes'
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        File.delete('C:\Users\USERNAME\file.txt')
        puts "Files Successfully deleted"
        sleep(5)
        exit
    when 'N', 'n', 'No', 'no'
        exit
    else
        puts "Invalid Character!"
        question?
    end
end
question?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
require 'fileutils'
puts "Please enter in your username:"
Username = gets.chomp
def question?
    puts "Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/N)"
    case gets.strip
    when 'Y', 'y', 'yes' 'Yes'
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        FileUtils.rm_rf('C:\Users\USERNAME')
        File.delete('C:\Users\USERNAME\file.txt')
        puts "Files Successfully deleted"
        sleep(5)
        exit
    when 'N', 'n', 'No', 'no'
        exit
    else
        puts "Invalid Character!"
        question?
    end
end
```

to:

```
  require 'fileutils'
  def question?
    puts "Please enter in your username:"
    username = gets.chomp
    puts "Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/N)"
    case gets.strip
    when 'Y', 'y', 'yes' 'Yes'
        FileUtils.rm_rf("C:/Users/#{username}")
        File.delete("C:/Users/#{username}/file.txt") #I doubt you need this line
        puts "Files Successfully deleted"
        sleep(5)
        exit
    when 'N', 'n', 'No', 'no'
        exit
    else
        puts "Invalid Character!"
        question?
    end
  end
```

You can only interpolate variables in double_quoted strings, you want to have your variables `username` in the scope of your method `question?`

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying _Invalid escape character syntax_? What causes this?

Comment: @Pan7h3r use forward_slash `/` instead of backslash `\\``, ruby is intelligent to use the right `FILE::SEPARATOR`